# How to show $(\alpha_n)\in l_\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Here, we have a sequence $(\alpha_n)$, and

let $T:l_1\rightarrow l_2: (x_n)\mapsto (\alpha_nx_n)$  is well-defined.

How to show that: $(\alpha_n)\in l_\infty$

Could you please help with this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose not: there exists an increasing sequence of integers $(n_k)_k$ such that $|a_{n_k}|\geqslant k$ for each $k$. The fact that the map $T$ is well-defined implies that if $(y_{n_k})_k$ is a sequence of real numbers such that $\sum_k |y_{n_k}|$ converges, then so does $\sum_k k^2y_{n_k}^2$.
Take $y_{n_k}=\frac 1{k\log^2 k}$ to get a contradiction.